# How to display extJS grid columns after each record, not only on the top

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

How to display extJS columns after each record not on the top.
I am grouping extJS grid with three columns and grouping is working fine.

Here is the code and we can test in fiddler as well.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId:'employeeStore',
            fields:['name', 'seniority', 'department', 'sort', 'groupsort'],
            grouper: {
               
                 groupFn: function(item) {
                    
                    return 'department: ' + item.get('department');
                }
            },

            // Have members of each group sorted on this field
            sorters: [{
                property: 'name'
            }],

            data: {'employees':[
                { "name": "Michael Scotts",  "seniority": 7, "department": "Management", "groupsort" : "2" },
                { "name": "Dwight Schrute", "seniority": 2, "department": "Sales", "groupsort" : "1" },
                { "name": "Jim Halpert",    "seniority": 3, "department": "Sales", "groupsort" : "1" },
                { "name": "Kevin Malone",   "seniority": 4, "department": "Accounting", "groupsort" : "3" },
                { "name": "Angela Martin",  "seniority": 5, "department": "Accounting", "groupsort" : "3" }
            ]},
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'employees'
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Employees',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
            columns: [
                { text: 'Name',     dataIndex: 'name' },
                { text: 'Seniority', dataIndex: 'seniority' },
                { text: 'Department', dataIndex: 'department', sortable: true }
            ],
            features: [{
                ftype: 'grouping'
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

My requierment is I want show columns not on the top but after the grouping for each record. Is there any workaround for that.

Comment: I am not sure there is an out-of-the box solution to add column header more than once. You can try to override and create a custom grid but it could mean a lot of work. You can use `groupHeaderTpl` to add columns' names or even a `html` `table` with  `th` tags but i won't  resize when columns are resized with the header etc.

Comment: You could play around with the summary row